# Undo svn update set-depth exclude

Tags: svn

I've excluded a folder in a subversion repository using:

`svn update set-depth exclude <dir>`

I would like to undo this action.

I have tried various `set-depth` options, such as `set-depth infinity` on the containing folder to no avail.

An ideas of how to undo this?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use a different command? In 1.8 an `svn update set-depth` should only affect your check-out (see [svn docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)) and you should be able to "undo" it at will as you suggested. You sure this wasn't ignored instead?

Comment: It is the command I used, and only the checked out version is affected. I'm looking for a way to undo the effect in the checked out folder.

Comment: It works like this: svn update set-depth infinity <dir>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved: the issue was that I had left the excluded folder in place in the directory. If I run:

`svn update set-depth infinity`

on the containing folder after removing the excluded sub-folder, it works. A little strange that it doesn't work if the sub-folder is in place, but I guess I understand.